# Talents after being overcome

Tags: samurai-spirit

Can talents of the samurai be used after the attack overcame the samurai?

The rulebook doesn't specify anything about this at the talents and the only effects the overcome seems to have is that

> Case 3: If the total is GREATER THAN your Kiai value, you are overcome by raiders: Immediately remove one village Barricade.

and in the next round

> Important: If your Samurai meeple is already past your Kiai value (i.e. on the flame), then you MUST PASS.

For some talents it would make sense that it can still be used as they are passive looking (at least to me). For example if Gorobei is overcome, he should(?) still be able to ignore the penalty on a Raider with an even value.

The real, specific question is: after Kikuchiyo becomes overcome by an attack, can he still use his talent and choose to fight another opponent even though he is already overcome?

Comment: What game is this so we can properly tag it?

Comment: @JoeW: Samurai Spirit https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/158900/samurai-spirit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antoine Bauza answered a question very similar to this one on [BoardGame Geek](https://boardgamegeek.com/article/17290330#17290330):

> [Question]1) After you have exceeded your Kiai value, but before you are obliged to pass on your next turn, can other players still pass on cards to you?
>
> [Response]1) Sure ! (it's important )
> When you exceeded your Kiaia Value, you have to brun immediately a barricade / farm. But you are force to tak ethe pass action on your next turn. So, a lot can happen before you're next turn (passing card, removing a card from your combat line). {*Sic*}

The direct implication to this is that:

1. Just because you've exceeded your Kiai value, your turn does not immediately pass.
2. Adding additional raider cards to a character who has exceeded his kiai value will not cause additional barricades to burn.
3. The character is still "in play" until the beginning of his next turn.

So, Kikuchiyo specifically, can take another raider, and either add it to his defense pile or his confrontation pile.